# Set the marker position in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to know how can I change the position of the marker in the Google Map.

Currently I'm using:

```
 var newlatlong = new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng());
 map.setCenter(newlatlong);
 marker.setPosition(newlatlong);
 map.setZoom(10);
```

Can I hand code the position of the marker in the map other than the center position?

I mean `map.setCenter(newlatlong);`, Instead of `setCenter` Is there any other position available? or can I hand code the position in the map where the marker should appear?

Comment: Are you talking about the mouse pointer position? or some marker?

Comment: Just make an edit to the question. It's the Map marker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you are running the code twice...

But yes, you can pass latitude/longitude values directly to the `setCenter` method

```
map.setCenter({lat: -34, lng: 151});
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

---

**update** after comments

If you want to move the map center so that the marker is specific position (in pixels), you can center on the marker and then use the `.panBy` method to move the map a fixed amount of pixels.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make any sense in the question. But what I wanted to know is the position of the pointer. Not the `lat` and `lng`. By default, the map pointer is set to the center.

Comment: @user1012181 what pointer are you talking about? Do you create a marker and place it on the map ?

Comment: @user1012181, when  you create a marker you can set its position with the [`position` option](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions), and for existing markers you can use the  [`setPosition` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) to reposition them.

Comment: `marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Main map',
            icon: iconBase + 'arrow.png'
        });`

Here, the position denotes the place latitude and longitude I guess!

Comment: @user1012181 yes you can pass lat/lng values there as well. `marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: {lat: -34, lng: 151}, map: map, title: 'Main map', icon: iconBase + 'arrow.png' });`

Comment: oh nooo!!!!! Forget about the lat and lng :) I'm talking about the x-y position of the marker. Not the lat and lng. Even with the code you provide, the marker is set to the center of the map.

Comment: @user1012181 not it is not. It is in the center only if you use the same lat/lng for both the marker and the center of the map. But you do not **have** to use the same. Example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/w0oweuvf/

Comment: So here, how can I set the marker position 30px above from the bottom with a zoomlevel of 10 ?

Comment: You can move the map in pixels with the `panBy` method. Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/w0oweuvf/2/

Comment: @user1012181 Your code has these two lines: `map.setCenter(newlatlong);  
marker.setPosition(newlatlong);`
Do you not understand that one sets the map center to `newlatlong`, and the other sets the marker position to the exact same spot? Like @GabyakaG.Petrioli said, use the `panBy` method if you want to shift the map center away from the marker position.

Answer (score 1):

To create a marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map : map,
   position : newlatlong
})
```

to update the position of this marker:

```
marker.setPosition(newlatlong);
```

to put the center at the east of marker, for example:

```
map.setCenter(new LatLng(newlatlong.lat,newlatlong.lng + 1.0))
```

Comment: `marker.setPosition(newlatlong)` is for the place. Still the position of the marker is at the center itself. I want to move the marker to the x-y direction.

Comment: if you set the same latlng to center of the map and to the marker, the marker will be.. at the center. If you don't want this, you can set the center to another position (some lng + x, for example, depends on you zoom level)

Comment: Yes, I want to know if I can change the position of the marker other than the center position.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the center of the map and the marker separately using different longitude and latitudes:

```
function initialize() {
   var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.512318, -72.979349);
   };

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.513001, -72.983845)
   });
};
```

This makes the marker slightly off center to the left. I used this in a current project of mine.